# Regular expressions for proxy pattern

Tags: java, regex, proxy, notepad++

From the list of text junk I'm using regular expression. The following will do that job to parse proxy pattern
    `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d{2,5}`. But This pattern parse the text like this:

`692.248.222.879:43780` 
`692.83.47.579:43780`

Which is not possible IP address. I want to know, how to skip this kind of ranges using regular expressions?

Tools I prefer: Java or C#, notepad++. However any languages will do.

Comment: Why would you want to do this with regular expressions? It's better to incapsulate such logic (checking for validness) inside some method in your application than in complex regular expression.

Comment: Since notepad++ is faster than my java code, I prefer this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b:\d{2,5}
```

'

```
692.248.222.879:43780 
692.83.47.579:43780
192.168.1.1:27052
```

works with the last one only

Comment: It did works. But since I've already come with this big selection, is there any other shorter possible regex for this result?

Comment: @William.Ebe, I don't think so. You really have to test a lot, even if it looks simple at the beginning. So - the best idea is to use some dedicated tool, that is tested and made for that purpose - as **minitech** mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

To validate numeric ranges with regular expressions, you have to supply every possible combination, which is why it's usually best to use built-in tools, like .NET's `IPAddress.TryParse`. But anyway...

```
((?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]):\d{2,5}
```

Comment: Thanks for .Net library reference; The above code don't parse exactly. It selects 692.248.222.879:43780 into **92.248.222.879:43780**. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: @William.Ebe: I'm trying it right now and it doesn't... but anyway, just add a `(?<!\d)` at the front and a `(?!\d)` at the end to make it not match anything in the middle of other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
"^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$:\d{2,5}";
```

[Proof](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/)